# unable to push a existing git repository to github

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, command-line

Their is an error I have been having for awhile on ubuntu that is not allowing me to push an existing repository from the command line. this error keeps showing up. How do I fix this.
Thank you

[image]

error: chmod on /mnt/e/myproject/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

Is this disk drive NTFS?, if not, please try using sudo.